# C# method doesnt execute or skips it instantly

Tags: c#, lego-mindstorms

I'm using a C# library (Monobrick) which has a method that opens and closes the arms of my robot. I can't view how the method is written since it's in a .dll.

My code looks something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    //true means to open, false means to close them
    MoveArms(true);
    MoveArms(false);
    ...WriteLine("Output");
}
```

The result is that the arms open once, and close once, and then it outputs "Output" 5 times instantly, and it just ignores the MoveArms() method...

Any idea on what's causing this? Or what solutions I could choose from? How can I troubleshoot? I don't know how to debug my program using the EV3 brick...

The class I'm using:

http://www.monobrick.dk/MonoBrickFirmwareDocumentation/class_mono_brick_firmware_1_1_movement_1_1_motor.html

Comment: Is it just happening too quickly? So you get open then close before it's had a chance to complete the open?

Comment: I don't have any particular familiarity with this library. But I'll just venture a guess that when you tell the robot to move its arms, you should then wait for the move to complete before issuing it another command regarding the arms.

Comment: I am not sure what's causing this, but you can try using a program like ILSpy to see what this function is doing.

http://ilspy.net/

Comment: @DavidG The arms open and close adequately the first time, and I get output 5 times instantly, so it just ignores the MoveArms() methods.

Comment: So if you add a delay after each `MoveArms` call, does it work?

Comment: @mason So why does it run synchronously first and then the second time it goes through the loop it just ignores it?

Comment: @user1534664 Like I said, I don't have any familiarity with the library. You should read the documentation. Or experiment with it enough that you understand how it works. This is a hobby/learning experience right?

Comment: @mason yeah, I've been doing trial and error with this method for 12 hours... There's little to no documentation on the library I'm using. I will try again tomorrow. Hopefully making the robot wait does something...

Comment: @user1534664 Does the MoveArms function return anything? e.g A boolean perhaps indicating whether the operation was successful or not.

Comment: There is no such method called `MoveArms` in the Monobrick API, is it? What is exactly the code that uses the API?

Comment: Add a Thread.Sleep(5000); right before the WriteLine(), and if needed in between the MoveArms() call and see if it works.

Comment: @PatriceGahide You are correct. I named it MoveArms to simplify it for people here. I'm actually using the MonoBrickFirmware library so not the MonoBrick API (they are seperate library's). And I'm using the Motor class. The method on the motor class i'm using is  SpeedProfileTime.

Comment: @PatriceGahide I provided a link to the class in my question.

Comment: Can you include the code for `MoveArms` It sounds like you need to wait for that function to complete movement before returning.

Comment: This method returns a `WaitHandle`. Try to wrap your calls with `WaitHandle.WaitAll()`.

Comment: @PatriceGahide Thank you... I think that should do the trick. I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: @PatriceGahide You were correct. It's working now, thanks. Can you create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpeedProfileTime` method that you use returns a `WaitHandle` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx)). You have to wait for the "motor" to complete its task before requiring something else from it. You can do that, for instance, by wrapping your calls with `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitall(v=vs.110).aspx)).